# Name of a circuit element. Switch or toggle?

Tags: differences, terminology, image-identification

What's correct name of this circuit element — switch or toggle?

[image: line connected to only one side, slanted]

Comment: This seems more a question about circuitry terminology than English. The image does not convey anything useful to those who are not already familiar with the domain. You can improve your question by providing a description of the diagram and giving a sample sentence which illustrates your desired use of "switch" or "toggle".

Comment: "Toggle" implies that the switch latches when operated.

Comment: The diagram is clear to those with even a basic scientific or electrical education such as accompanies a basic education in the use of English. The question is clear and a unique answer exists (a switch may select one of many positions whereas a toggle alternates between only two positions). The question therefore should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the symbol is "switch". See [BBC Bitesize Electrical Circuit Symbols](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zgvq4qt/revision/1).

Comment: A *toggle* is a switch, but it's a particular **type** of switch, generally with a [lever which is moved up and down](https://www.google.com/search?q=electrical+toggle+switch&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 2):

A switch is a circuit element which is intended to connect or disconnect an electric current, so what you show is a switch.  In UK usage the word 'switch' is often combined with another word to show what sort of physical switch is meant, so a toggle switch is operated by a lever (as stated by Andrew Leach). In my fifty-plus years of electrical engineering I have not come across 'toggle' on its own in this context.

There are also rocker switches, push switches, tilt switches and many others.